# mysql system command

Tags: mysql, system, cd

I am in MySQL and would like to change the current working directory. I tried to execute:

```
mysql> system cd './my_dir'
```

However, this does not seem to work. Has anyone run into a similar problem?

Comment: operating system `windows` or `linux` ? Because `system` command only works on `unix/linux` platform.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System is going to spawn a child process to run a shell command.....

Current working directory is a process level property....so you can't change it in the parent from a child process.  That's why it doesn't work.

I briefly scanned the MySQL docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-commands.html but didn't see a direct CD command that changes the working directory. I think an adventurous person could write one....

Comment: i see. is there a way to change the current working directory once you are in mysql?

Comment: It does seem like there ought to be a "cd" or "chdir" command already, even if undocumented.  Did you try those? If you can write an extension in "C", or want to modify the source, all it might need to do is call the chdir system call with the directory name. see  http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir

Comment: Normally you would switch to a directory of your choosing, like the one containing your scripts, before starting the MySQL shell.

Comment: Yes, that would be easier. But maybe they have a good reason to need to chdir that we haven't anticipated.

Comment: @Claude excellent point! I'm a newb teaching myself mysql. I was trying to save the sample database http://eclipse.org/birt/documentation/sample-database.php and trying to figure out how to change directory to location where scripts were saved. saw your comment and started shell only after switching to directory where script were located. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change your current working directory for a script, then use the && between the CD and script so it will change directory and then if that's successful it will execute the second command.

```
mysql> SYSTEM cd /home && ls
```

Comment: this is valid and prints the contents of `/home` but does not change the current working directory. E.g. mysql will seek files relative to the CWD where you were when you entered the mysql shell

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is the escape to shell command: `\!`

```
mysql>\! cd ./my_dir
```

You can even use it to escape to the shell completely and then come back to the mysql environment.

```
mysql>\! bash
bash>cd ./my_dir
bash>exit
mysql>SELECT * ALL FROM <table>;
```

Comment: Hey @MrSampson, nice first answer.

Comment: I think I should add that this seems to work for everything **but** changing the local working directory. Grrr. When you exit from bash and execute \! pwd it shows the original directory that mysql was executed from.

Comment: That's because when you do `\! bash` you're creating a new shell environment.

Comment: Ya, this doesn't really fix the issue the questioner (and I) is trying to solve, but I upvoted just because THAT'S WICKED!  Thanks, @MrSampson. :)